# Issue in Python Logging using dictConfig

Tags: python, django, logging

Below is the configuration dict i am using:

```
LOGGING_CONF = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': { 
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(message)s'
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
    },
},
'handler': { 
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'formatter': 'verbose',
        'filename': 'D:\workspace\yogasync\codes\code_svn\YogaSync\log\workspacelogconfig.log',
        'maxBytes': 20480,
        'backupCount': 3, 
     },
},
'logger': {
    'extensive': {
        'level':'DEBUG',
        'handlers': 'file'
    },
},
```

}

in a module where i need to create logs i have inserted the below code:

```
import logging
import logging.config 
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING_CONF)

logger = logging.getLogger('extensive')

logger.info("This is my first log")
```

When i execute this, no errors are raised, however no logs get created.
I am not sure what is missing out. I want to use dictCongif only
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a handler so that something happens with all those loggers. For example,

```
logfile = logging.handlers.FileHandler("mylog.log")
logfile.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logfile.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(module)s: %(message)s'))
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(logfile)
```

Comment: We can configure logging in three ways:

1.    Creating loggers, handlers, and formatters explicitly using Python code that calls the configuration methods listed above.
2.    Creating a logging config file and reading it using the fileConfig() function.
3.    Creating a dictionary of configuration information and passing it to the dictConfig() function. 
 you have mentioned the 1st way of logging. i want to do it using 3rd method(dictConfig)

Comment: @Arun: oh in this case maybe the `loggers` key should be a list? it is `handlers` not `handler`. so have `'extensive': { 'level': 'DEBUG', 'handlers': ['file']}`

Comment: Thank You, 
it should be handlers not handler and loggers not logger.(Stupid mistake)
and yes handlers should be a list.

Thanks, you helped me getting a beer bottle . ;)

Comment: ohh what is the malted liquor, what gets you drunker quicker, what comes in bottles or in caaans? BEER!

Comment: at our workplace we keep chilled beer ready for those who finish there days work at the earlist and today its CARLSBERG in bottle

Comment: @Claudiu, This is working now, however its not runnign on other machines. other developer download the code from snv and trying on his machine. but again its not logging into the files.